# typedef struct: unknown name

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I am confused by my actual problem... Could also be my mistake

Short description with code:

rtc.h

```
#ifndef RTC_H_
#define RTC_H_

typedef struct timestamp_t
{
    uint8_t year,month,day,hour,minute,second;
}timestamp_t;

#endif /* RTC_H_ */
```

lpwa.h

```
#ifndef LPWA_H_
#define LPWA_H_

#include "rtc.h"

timestamp_t lpwa_ntp_to_stamp(char*); //shows error: unknown name timestamp_t

#endif /* LPWA_H_ */
```

lpwa.c

```
#include "lpwa.h"

timestamp_t lpwa_ntp_to_stamp(char *text) //no problem
{
    ...
}
```

If I copy the typedef struct to lpwa.h it says "confliction types for timestamp_t"

Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Comment: With the shown code that should not occur. But the shown code is not what you use (juding from the syntax-breaking `...`). Sorry if this sounds pedantic, but please double check that what you have shown is really a [mre] which demonstrates your problem. I suspect that there is a hidden or indirect additional `#include` somewhere which is not visible here.

Comment: Please insert lines like this into both involved header files. `#error Header A is compiled` ("A" -> "B" for the second). This will allow you to determine the order of includes (assuming it to be more complex than shown here) and also to make sure that the files you are looking at are really the files which the compiler includes. This is a widely spread mistake during debugging, not trying to make fun of you....

Comment: Thank you! It's actually a big program, so it would be a huge afford to remove things step by step. I was wondering if someone knows "common mistakes" causing this problem.

Comment: Common mistakes: Another c file includes differently than you think. One of the headers includes the other differently than you think. The files you are looking at are not those used during build. All of the above.... My second comment describes how to debug that. Making a MRE does not necessarily mean removing things from the whole program (though that is the constructive way forward). You can start at the end and make a MRE of what you think happens, it will however probably show that the problem is not present like you think. Using that as helpful info requires experience...

Comment: If you start your MRE at the end you need to actively try to provoke the problem you see. Try this: from rtc.h include lpwa.h before doing the typedef. I think that could get you the desribed error in the shown MRE. If that is true try to find that include in your actual code. You probably then have just missed it while making the MRE you show here.

Comment: We're getting there. If I include lpwa.h in rtc.h the error doesn't occur. I'll dig deeper

Comment: Playing with `#error` lines is the enlightening path to walk. Insert one and try to predict (as opposed to try) exactly when it occurs in comparison to other `#error`lines. Insert them before and after `#include`. Insert them before and inside the `#ifndef' lines you have.

Comment: Keep a close eye on which of your code files causes which error.

Comment: It shows `#error Header LPWA` first an then `#error Header RTC`
That's the wrong order i think.

Comment: See? Your experiemtns show that what you think happens is not what does happen. It might even match my error-provoking proposal. (Again, I am not making fun of you, honestly.) You need to do the hard work of really putting the include order (somebody call it include tree) into your MRE exactly as it is in your actual code. Keep in mind that you surely have more than one code file. Each code file is the root of one include tree. You need to be aware of all the trees.

Comment: Yes, now I found my problem! There was a mistake with my include tree. I forgot about a obsolete header, which is the root for my problems.
So you were right!
Thank you!
PS: It doesn't felt like you we're making fun of me at any point. I know that I'm a beginner and need to learn things by making (stupid) mistakes

Comment: I made a general answer. Remember that making your own answer with the specific solution in your case is appreciated on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an answer compiled from my debugging recommendations which helped OP to find the actual problem:

- The shown code should not exhibit the described problem. This actually is helpful information, because it means that the structure of your actual code is different and you need to find that difference to trace the problem to the root.
- The problem is probably in the include order, aka include tree, being different than you think.
- Inserting `#error Header A is compiled` `#error Header B is compiled` generously in all likely and unlikely places of your project will give you an idea of the actual include tree, allowing you to look for differences to the imagined include tree. (Use `#warning` if your compiler supports it, then you get more than only the first `#error` encountered.)
- The constructive way to debug this is to make a StackOverflow-style minimal reproducible example.
- If making a classic MRE/MCVE ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ) seems too much work (it is not, trust me), then try making a MRE of what you think happens, from scratch. That will at least show you that what you think happens is NOT what actually happens. This is also helpful information, though making use of it requires experience and discipline. (Thanks for not feeling mocked here.)
- Keep in mind that each source code file "*.c" is the root of another include tree.
- Playing with `#error` will also alert you of the possible problem that you look at different files (e.g. in your editor) than the compiler actually processes. (Again, not mocking. That happens more often, to me, than I'd like to admit....)

Above is general.

Specifically in your case, I suspect that there is a hidden/indirect `#include "lwpa.h"` inside rtc.h, between the shown include and the shown typedef. (And I think you confirmed that.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I know your associatoin. But try writing in a comment `[mre]`. I believe it means that MRE is official on StackOverflow. Though of course `[mcve]` also works.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Did use your link though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I have seen your contributions here. Your compliment is at least as appreciated as the upvotes I got (irrelevant whether one of them is from you.)

Comment: Thank you for your help and also for the answer. If there would be more people like you, there would be less people like me.
And YES, I confirmed that last sentence of your answer.

Comment: Having less people like you would be sad. Have fun. Try to give what you appreciate receiving.

Comment: That's how you build a community and help the next generation learn to code -- correctly..